# how to change dbplyr's show_query() quote covention for snowflake SQL

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbplyr

I am using dbplyr's package to translate my dplyr's query to SQL  and it works really well, however when I copy and paste my translated SQL statement it wont run in snowflake because the quotes the columns with ` (the key above tab), whereas my snowflake SQL will only run if its columns are quoted with either " (double quote) ' (single quote) or no quote at all (if there are no breaks).

Is there a way to change the dbplyr::show_query() argument so that the outcome is in double quotes or single quotes instead of backtick? there is a `con` argument which I've set to `simulate_snowflake()` however that doesn't change anything.

The error I get is: SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 0 invalid identifier '"`COL_NAME`"'

```
#This will not work in my snowflake SQL


SELECT 
`COL_NAME`
FROM
TABLENAME

#This will work though:
SELECT 
"COL_NAME"
FROM
TABLENAME
```

Comment: Can you do something like `<pipeline> %>%  sql_render() %>%  as.character() %>% 
  str_replace_all(pattern="`",replacement = "\\\"") ?

Comment: @langtang works! I had to adjust the replacement argument (I just left it blank). Thank you so much!

Comment: I've added as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `sql_render()`, convert to a character string, and use any regex replace process that you like to change the quotes. For example:

```
<pipeline> %>%
  sql_render() %>%
  as.character() %>%
  str_replace_all(pattern="`",replacement = "\\\"")
```